# UNWIND is not returning in neo4j

Tags: performance, neo4j

Consider the follwing CQL Query

```
MATCH (n:Label1) WITH n
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:REL_1]-(:Label2 {id: 5})
WHERE r is NULL OR r.d < 12345 OR (r.d = 12345 OR r.c < 2)
WITH n,r LIMIT 100
WITH COLLECT({n: n, r: r}) AS rows
MERGE (c:Label2 {id: 5})
WITH c,
[b IN rows WHERE  b.r.d IS NULL OR b.r.d < 12345] AS null_less_rows,
[c IN rows WHERE (c.r.d = 12345 AND c.r.c < 2)] AS other_rows
WITH null_less_rows, other_rows, c, null_less_rows+other_rows AS rows, size(null_less_rows+other_rows) AS count
UNWIND null_less_rows AS null_less_row
MERGE(s:Label1 {id: null_less_row.n.id})
MERGE(s)-[:REL_1 {d: 12345, c: 1}]->(c)
WITH DISTINCT other_rows, c, rows, count
UNWIND other_rows AS other_row
MATCH(s:Label1 {id: other_row.n.id})-[str:REL_1]->(c) SET str.c = str.c + 1
WITH rows, count
RETURN rows, count
```

When I excute the query, It should return rows and count (according to query). But instead of returning rows, count it's giving result statement.

```
Set 200 properties, created 100 relationships, statement completed in 13 ms.
```

Is there any problem with query structure or problem with improper use of UNWIND clause.

Comment: Try insert `RETURN other_rows, rows, count` after last `MERGE` (and comment all after). What will be the result? P.S. For the future: if you are asking to help understand a complex query - gives an example of the input data on which this query can be checked. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addition to Micheael Hunger Answer

```
UNWIND (CASE other_rows WHEN [] then [{n:{id: -2}}] else other_rows end) AS other_row
```

As I am operating on values of array, instead of null, I need to add extra condition so that it can't throw any error mesaages.

This apllies for both cases (other_rows, null_less_rows)

Answer (score 0):

If other_rows is null or empty, UNWIND will not produce any rows.

You could solve it with:

```
UNWIND case coalesce(size(other_rows),0) when 0 then [null] else other_rows end 
   as other_row
```